# Modifying column headers of JTable with MySQL data

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I have a JTable that retrieves information from a MySQL database table. The column headers are named just like how they are in the database.

Here is the code to create the JTable:

```
JScrollPane spBlockViewSchedule = new JScrollPane();
spBlockViewSchedule.setBounds(10, 285, 763, 185);
pnlBlockSched.add(spBlockViewSchedule);

tblBlockViewSchedule = new JTable();
spBlockViewSchedule.setViewportView(tblBlockViewSchedule);
```

Here is the code that populates the JTable:

```
private void populateTable(String sql, JTable table) {
        try {
            pst = DbConnection.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
```

How do I change the column names displayed in the JTable without changing the column names of the database table itself?

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty DefaultTableModel with code like:

```
String[] columnNames = {"Course Code", "Subject Code", "Year Level", ...};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
```

Then in the code where you read the data from the ResultSet you add the data to the TableMOdel using the `addRow(....)` method. Something like:

```
while (rs.next())
{
   Vector row = new Vector();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }

    model.addRow( row );
}
```

Finaly you create the table using:

```
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Edit:

Since you are using 3rd party code you either need to change the way you add data to the model. I gave you basic code above. You can see the `Table From Database Example` source code from [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a complete example.

Or, you can modify the column headers after the table is created with code like:

```
table.getColumn("course_code").setHeaderValue("Course Code");
...
table.repaint();
```

Edit 2:

You can get the TableColumn from the TableColumnModel:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getTableColumnModel();
tcm.getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Course Code");
...
table.repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. It might be what I need. I have added the method that populates the JTable to the post. Would you kindly modify this answer to coincide with the populateTable() method just posted?

Comment: @ohtph, `I have added the method that populates the JTable to the post` - no you didn't. You added code that executes a 3rd party class. Unless you can change that code, it doesn't help us. See edit.

Comment: I have placed the setHeaderValue() approach below the code that creates the JTable. However, it is throwing an `IllegalArgumentException: Identifier not found`.

Comment: @ohtph, works fine for me, I guess you specified the "identifier" incorrectly. The other approach is to get the column from the TableColumnModel. See edit 2.

Comment: Eclipse is returning an error unless `getTableColumnModel()` is changed to `getColumnModel()`. It is also throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @ohtph, I can't debug your code. If you are getting Exceptions then that means you haven't created the JTable and added the TableModel to the table yet. The basic answer it the TableColumn contains the value that is displayed on the frame. Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables`. Download the example code from there and try the changes I have suggested to prove to yourself that the concept works. Then figure out what you are doing wrong with your own code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. The column header names were just a minor qualm anyway.

Comment: @ohtph, Not sure what the above comment means. I gave you the answer to your question, so I don't know why you haven't accepted the answer. If you are still not able to change the headings, then you are making some kind of silly mistake because as I have suggested in my answer, the solution is 1/2 lines of code. If you can't understand how to make this change, then how can you possibly understand how your code works. That is NOT the way to write a program.

Comment: I do not deny it is of my own shortcoming that I was not able to make this work (but all my other questions here in StackO, I was able to). However, I mark answers as accepted answer, only AFTER I can *personally* attest to it myself (not because I was forced to). Accepting this answer when I have not clearly understood it is lying (to myself at least). With that, I can only upvote your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ohtph, `Accepting this answer when I have not clearly understood it is lying (to myself at least).` - did you even download the example code from the tutorial and add the two lines of code that I suggested? How do you ever expect to learn when you are not willing to try what has been suggested? Once you prove to yourself that the suggestion works, you look at your code to see what the difference is. I fail to see how you can not understand two lines of code. All you need to do is add the code after the data has been added to the table.

Comment: Hi, I would just like you to know that Edit2 worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently facing the same problem as you did.

This line:

```
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

provided by r2xml.jar is pretty handy :)

I ***overcame the problem*** by setting **alias** to my **sql SELECT statement**. 
For example,

```
SELECT 
EngagementMethodID AS [ID],
EngagementMethodDescription AS [Engagement Method Description]

 FROM [STUDENT].[EngagementMethod]
```

This will populate the column header as **ID** and **Engagement Method Description** as wanted.

Hope it helps.. Despite the age of this question? haha... Just sharing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       int colCount = 0;
       ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = null;
        colCount = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int k = 1; k <= colCount; k++) {
       { String columnName = null;

        columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(k);
        System.out.println(columnName);
        }
```

use this code simultaneously with your fetching code.

Comment: that's probably similar to what the OP is already doing ... the headers are the same as those in the DB which is explicitly **not** what the OP needs

Answer (score 0):

Each JTable has a TableModel. This TableModel defines the columns(Names and data types)

so find your table model and change it accordingly.

Comment: I have tried initializing a String[] columnNames to no avail and using DefaultTableModel, however, I am unsure how to put the data in the parameters, since they are from the database. More detailed assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us how the data is being added to the table from the database.

Comment: I have added the method that populates the JTable to the post. Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: `I have added the method that populates the JTable to the post` - no you didn't. You added code that executes a 3rd party class. Unless you can change that code, it doesn't help us.